# angular put code from a form into a [POST]

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http, data-binding

I have

```
var body = {username:"ali", password:"p"};
    this.http.post('http://localhost:27017/user/auth', body).subscribe(data => 
{console.log(data);});
```

How can I load up the variable body with some data-binding from a form?  I'm just making a login - I have two fields, username and password that the user enters, and then that will go into the second .post() parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**html code**

```
<input type="text"  id="username" required [(ngModel)]="user.username">
<input type="password"  id="password" required [(ngModel)]="user.password">
<button (click)="submit()">submit</button>
```

**ts code**

```
user={username:"", password:""};
submit(){
const body = this.user;
    this.http.post('http://localhost:27017/user/auth', body).subscribe(data => 
{console.log(data);});
}
```

EDIT: You need of course to add test for the form for more information https://angular.io/guide/forms